# WPF - Problem accessing Roboto fonts by font name

Tags: wpf, xaml, fonts, truetype, roboto

I have downloaded the Roboto font from [dafunt.com](https://www.dafont.com/roboto.font).
In my application, I require to use three Roboto-fonts:

- Roboto Bold
- Roboto Medium
- Roboto Regular

But I have trouble identifying how to access the correct font by its font name in my WPF-application.
If I open each font-file in Window's `Character map` application I can see what I think are the font names. These  are:

```
File-name             Font name
===============================
Roboto-Bold.ttf       Roboto
Roboto-Medium.ttf     Roboto Lt
Roboto-Regular.ttf    Roboto
```

Notice `Robot-Bold` and `Roboto-Regular` have the **same font name**.

So I'm confused about how to access the correct font in my WPF-application.

In my Visual Studio project, I have created a folder called `Fonts`. The three font files are placed in that folder and the font files are included in my project. The `Build Action` is set to `Resource` of each font file.

**XAML-code**

```
<Window x:Class="Main.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Main"
    xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="RobotoBold">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Main;component/Fonts/#Roboto" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="RobotoMedium">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Main;component/Fonts/#Roboto Lt" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="RobotoRegular">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Main;component/Fonts/#Roboto" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="RobotoBoldV2">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Main;component/Fonts/#Roboto Bold" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="RobotoMediumV2">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Main;component/Fonts/#Roboto Medium" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="RobotoRegularV2">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Main;component/Fonts/#Roboto Regular" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="asdf1" Style="{StaticResource RobotoBold}" />
        <TextBlock Text="asdf2" Style="{StaticResource RobotoMedium}" />
        <TextBlock Text="asdf3" Style="{StaticResource RobotoRegular}" />
        <Separator Height="6" Visibility="Hidden" />
        <TextBlock Text="asdf4" Style="{StaticResource RobotoBoldV2}" />
        <TextBlock Text="asdf5" Style="{StaticResource RobotoMediumV2}" />
        <TextBlock Text="asdf6" Style="{StaticResource RobotoRegularV2}" />
        <Separator Height="6" Visibility="Hidden" />
        <TextBlock Text="asdf7" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I have included an image of the application in the Designer.

[image]

Notice there are some variations of the font for some of the TextBlocks.
These variations are what I cannot understand.

- asdf1: Seem to have changed by the font Roboto. If this is Roboto-Bold or Roboto-Regular is unknown.
- asdf2: Seem to be unchanged.
- asdf3: Is the same as `asdf1` naturally.
- asdf4: I tried with `Roboto Bold` but it didn't work.
- asdf5: For some reason `Roboto Medium` works. But there is no font file with the name `Roboto Medium`.
- asdf6: I tried with `Roboto Regular` but it didn't work.
- asdf7: Just for comparison. Seems to be the same font as `asdf2`, `asdf4` and `asdf6`.

This is so confusing.
I'm sure I use the correct syntax to reference the font files in the XAML-code. But since the font names don't seem too reliable I'm not sure which fonts are used in my TextBlocks.

Any suggestion on how to clear this mess?

Comment: In the example image, the default font looks pretty similar to Roboto. If you re-run it at some point, maybe use Times or something like that which is more distinct, just to tell them apart more easily? Sorry though I can't answer your actual question :(

Comment: I think if the font names are the same you can access more options through `FontWeight` property

Answer (score 0):

I added another TextBlock, bellow my ASDF1 TextBlock, but with not Font and same Text.
I was able to see some difference.
So the fonts actually work.
Thanks @UuDdLrLrSs.

Still strange that `Roboto-Bold` and `Roboto-Regular` has the same font name.